# iOS autofill username and password from SMS

Tags: ios, autofill, ios12

I have a problem with autofill from SMS. For now, I'm getting SMS from provider with **Login - xxxx, and Password - xxxx**. I have two fields, login and password and need to put that **login part to login field**, and **passcode to password field**. Is there any way to achieve this? 
P.S. One time code, is not what I'm searching for, thank you.

Screenshot of what I need - https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRnZv.png

Comment: This is not possible in iOS for now.

Comment: iOS doesn't allow you to read messages. So, no it's not possible to achieve.

Comment: @PinkeshGjr iOS 12 currently support it. It's not autofill. It could display on status menu above virtual keyboard.

Comment: @nayem iOS 12 currently support it. It's not autofill. It could display on status menu above virtual keyboard.

Comment: @PyaePhyoeShein can you please bring example link or tutorial or something like that?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. SMS message will be displayed on status bar above virtual keyboard.

Comment: @PyaePhyoeShein My problem is, that I'm getting SMS with login and password in it, but I need to copy that two codes and place it in my username and password fields. That's what I need, not to just see displayed message. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelGrigoryan could you check my answer?

Comment: @nayem could you refer apple link I've shared. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view

Answer (score 0):

please check it out following links:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view

and here is sample code:

```
@available(iOS 12.0, *)
public static let oneTimeCode: UITextContentType

myTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Pyae, this is what I want to achieve, please look at this link.
https://i.imgur.com/8r4u2Wi.png

Comment: @MichaelGrigoryan I've edited my answer as to add image. There is `textContentType` already.

Comment: @ Pyae Phyoe Shein I've added image too, and setting type as .username or password not working. Thank you.

Comment: P.S. I don't want to user password autofill from Keychain or iClouse or something like that, I want to read username and password from SMS and fill it into my text fields. Thanks again.

Comment: It should not be auto fill. User need to tap on username display on status bar and it will be automatically filled after that.

Comment: Well, this autofill is for ___if your device/icloud had previously stored credentials___. It's not for sms based login authentication.

Comment: @Pyae Phyoe Shein Well, it is not filling, that's what the problem.

Comment: @MichaelGrigoryan yap, it's not autofilling. User need to click at least to fill it. Please check my answer again. I've edited.

Comment: @Pyae Phyoe Shein When user's get message, and AUTOMATICALLY that message data fills into text fields, I don't know how to name it else. Thank you for your answer.